# Difference between pipe and stream in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pipe, fs

Here's my code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const src = fs.createReadStream('bigfile3.txt');
const des = fs.createWriteStream('newTest.txt');
```

I can use either

```
src.on('data',(chunk)=>{
des.write(chunk);});
```

Or

```
src.pipe(des);
```

Is there any difference between this two ways of handling the file operation? The pipe method gives me an error of 
`> "size" argument must not be larger than 2147483647` whenever I try with a large file.(~2GB)

Can anyone explain the working behind pipe and stream? Thanks.

Comment: No difference . All the streams are instances of Event-emitter. They emit events that can be used to read and write data and pipe method provides a simpler method to consume streams data.This article explains the concept of streams in depth [link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the pipe method because the flow of data will be automatically managed so that the destination Writable stream is not overwhelmed by a faster Readable stream.

If your readable stream is faster than the writable stream then you may experience data loss in `des.write(data)` method so better you should use `src.pipe(des);`

If the file size is big then you should use streams, thats the correct way of doing it, I tried similar example like yours to copy 3.5 GB file with streams and pipe, it worked flawlessly in my case. Check you must be doing something wrong.

The example which I tried

```
'use strict'

const fs =require('fs')
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./Archive.zip')
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./Archive3.zip')


readStream.pipe(writeStream)
```

However, if you still need to use stream `des.write(data)`, you can handle backpressure to avoid loss of data when `readStream` is faster. If the response from `des.write(data)` is `false`, then the `writeStream` is loaded, pause the readStream `src.pause()`.

To continue when `writeStream` is drained, handle `drain` event on writeStream and resume in the callback.

```
des.on("drain", () => src.resume())
```

To allow higher writeStream buffer memory, you can set `highWaterMark` for `readStream` to a very high value, example

```
const des = fs.createWriteStream('newTest.txt',{
     highWaterMark: 1628920128
});
```

Be careful of too massive `highWaterMark` because this takes of too much memory and defeat the primary advantage of streaming data.

I will definitely still recommend using `pipe` as this handles everything for you with lesser code.

Docs:

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options